# Как сделать поиск города рФ?1

Tags: javascript, ajax

Каким образом реализовать на чистой верстке такой функционал?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В России более 1100 городов, как можно по поиску получить?

Comment: любой внешний `api`, который предоставляет данный функционал